# segmenting human point cloud into 6 main parts

Tags: matlab, opencv, 3d, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have a point cloud of a human and want to segemnt it into 6 main parts including:
hands, feet, head, ...

how can I do this using opencv or pcl library or matlab? which segmentation or clustring algurithm can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that graph cut algorithms may be intresting for you, try search by phrase:
"graph cut mesh segmentation".
And also look here: http://people.cs.umass.edu/~kalo/papers/LabelMeshes/

Answer (score 0):

pcl has a pass-through filter, which allows you to apply split-planes on the 3d cloud

(no idea, why anyone'd downvote on this, btw)